# When is casting away const legal or illegal? (gcc, clang, and MSVC)

Tags: c, casting, constants, language-lawyer, c99

When is casting away `const` illegal?

In many cases `const` is simply an annotation for the benefit of the user which is enforced by the compiler. This question is asking for when casting away `const` is strictly illegal and what part of the C99 standard forbids it (if any)?

I suspect that it must be illegal in some cases because I've observed that `const` function pointers in the global scope are sometimes inlined by gcc. If these function pointers could be legally modified later in the program then this optimization would be invalid. Additionally I'm pretty sure I've read an explanation for when casting away `const` is illegal on StackOverflow but I just can't find it. (I think the answer was that `const` can only be cast away when a variable was originally not declared as `const`.)

I've tagged this C99 because I'm hoping this is something specified in the C99 standard but if an answer can explain behavior common to the gcc, clang, and MSVC implementations of C99 then that would also be sufficient for me.

(Obviously this is very basic question so I did try and fail to find a duplicate *specifically for the C standard*. If anyone else can point me to an exact duplicate I'll be happy to close vote. In either case, I think this question title at least helps SSO for this sort of question.)

Comment: Are you asking "when is this not allowed by the standard" or "when does this not work"? The answer to the former is "almost always"; the answer to the latter is "almost never".

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 For this question I want an answer as per the standard (hence 'languge-lawyer' tag) although I wouldn't mind extra commentary about when it will work. (PS I edited another paragraph into the question after your comment.) Also, I don't think "also never" is the right answer for when casting away `const` is legal. (Obviously I could be wrong -- hence the question!)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of when it is allowed at all; for the most part, it isn't. On the other hand, it works anytime the value isn't a literal (literals are typically embedded in the source code, and most OSes won't let you modify the code of program in memory).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Casting away constness in never illegal. You can do it freely and legally as much as you want. But attempting to *modify* the pointed object after casing away the constness might lead to undefined behavior (or it might not, depending on the circumstances).

C99 clearly states

> **6.7.3 Type qualifiers**
>
> **5** If an attempt is made to modify an object defined with a const-qualified type through use of an lvalue with non-const-qualified type, the behavior is undefined.

(it is 6.7.3/6 in C11).

Note that `const` in C (and C++) is used in two independent and very different roles: const-qualification of *an object itself* and const-qualification of an *access path* to an object.

```
const int a = 42;  // `a` is a const-qualifiet object

int b = 5;         // `b` is not const-qualified
const int *p = &b; // `*p` is a const-qualified access path to `b`
```

In the latter case the constness can be legally cast away and the resultant non-const access path can be used to modify the object, provided the object itself is not const

```
*(int *) p = 6; // nothing formally wrong with it
```

This is the very reason we have the ability to cast away constness in the language.

But the former (constness of the object itself) cannot be overridden

```
*(int *) &a = 43; // undefined behavior
```

The reason is pretty trivial - a const object can be physically located in read-only memory. And even if it isn't, the compiler is still free to compile the code under assumption that the object's value never changes.

This means that in a declaration like

```
const int *const cp = &b;
```

these two `const` have quite different meanings. The first (leftmost) one is a "soft" `const`, which can be overridden if the conditions are right. But the second `const` is a "hard" `const` that cannot be overridden.

So, when you say that "`const` is simply an annotation for the benefit of the user which is enforced by the compiler", it is only true for const-qualifications of access paths. When it comes to const-qualifications of objects themselves, it is generally a lot more that just just a purely conceptual compiler-enforced "annotation".

Comment: Nice answer, thanks. Just to be clear, is the rest of the answer your own paraphrasing of the quote from that standard that you give? The distinction you explain, *const-qualification of an object itself and const-qualification of an access path to an object* is nice and clear but I just want to know if a phrase like "const access-path" is something defined by the standard that I should expect others will understand.

Comment: @Praxeolitic: I borrowed the concept of "access path" from C++ standard, where it is used colloquially in equivalent contexts without a formal definition. So, this is not a formal term, but rather something that's intended to be self-explanatory.

Comment: Unfortunately, the C Standard is rather murky about what constitutes "an object".  Given `int const *p = calloc(1, sizeof(int));`, what is considered to be the type of the object identified by `*p`?  Is it an `int`, an `int const`, or something else?

Comment: @supercat The object accessed through your `*p` has no declared type and the effective type const int. Until you fix the effective type with a write or memcpy, each read establishes one just for that read. 6.5/6 in C11